# Code for inserting data into SQL Server database using Enterprise library

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am new to C# Windows Application coding and using Enterprise library.

I want to insert records into SQL Server 2008 database using Enterprise Library 4.1

I am getting confused between SQLCommand and DBCommand which one to use and when to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use EntLib, just use old good ADO.NET:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (@param)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

Here's the class signature on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx):

```
public sealed class SqlCommand : DbCommand, ICloneable
```

SqlCommand derives from DbCommand

Answer (score 6):

`DbCommand` (in the System.Data.Common namespace) is an abstract base class from which `SqlCommand`, `OleDbCommand`, `OdbcCommand`. `OracleCommand`, etc all are derived.

Answer (score 2):

SQLcommand is a subclass of DBcommand. Use SQLcommand if you are connecting to SQL server

Answer (score 0):

you can first try using SQLCommand - example [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-sqlcommand-executereader.htm)

and refer [this](http://www.debugging.com/bug/18994) if you want further information on SQL and DBCommand.