# How do i insert data into database using HTML controls?

Tags: asp.net, html, post, get

I have a ASP.NET application and SQL server database. I want to insert a data into my table using a button click event. It is a HTML button.

Comment: paste the html code please. Is it a form? Is it a GET or a POST request?

Comment: <form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: @Heinzi: I don't have idea to do this work. I'm beginner in this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Your task has two components: Handling an ASP.NET button click, and inserting data into an SQL Server database.

- For the first part, you can find a sample in the MSDN documentation of [the Button.Click event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx).
- For the second part, you can find a simple example in the first answer of following SO question: [Code for inserting data into SQL Server database using Enterprise library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6160413/87698)

Combing the two is left as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Comment: My button is not an ASP control. Its HTML button. <input type="submit" value="Submit">

Comment: @Venil: If you are a beginner, I suggest you start with the basics, which is to use the built-in ASP.NET controls. Manually processing form POST is a more advanced topic.

Comment: Currently i'm using ASP control. I said that i'm beginner to use HTML button. I think my post was not clear. Sorry Heinzi