# Read data from a external webpage and store that into my database

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I read data from a external webpage and store that into my database.

if I already have permission to access that data from that external webpage?

I am using sql server 2008.

Comment: Do you want to read formatted data, like JSON, XML, CSV or web.service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your position I would use c# and do:

1. Get data from website -> [Reading data from a website using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758283/c-sharp-reading-data-from-a-website)
2. Write data to sql database -> [Code for inserting data into SQL Server database using Enterprise library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160413/code-for-inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-enterprise-library)