# Transfer data from CRM database to SQL Database using Plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I am new to CRM and C# , can anyone please give some brief information and steps on transferring data from CRM database to SQL database using C# plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [SSIS Integration Toolkit](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm). You would not need to write any code to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get data into SQL Server is probably to use ADO.NET to insert/update records.

Here's a SO answer on how to do that: [Code for inserting data into SQL Server database using Enterprise library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160413/code-for-inserting-data-into-sql-server-database-using-enterprise-library)

As for getting the data from Dynamics CRM, my suggestion would be to look in the Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK which contains many examples for different development scenarios.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Also here's a fairly detailed walkthrough.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695782.aspx